# Log4cxx is slow when used without critical section

Tags: c++, logging, boost-thread, log4cxx

I am doing performance testing on log4cxx. When I call LOG4CXX_XXXXX directly the following code takes around 10 secs to finish logging everything. But when I enclose the call with boost::lockguard (which I think is a critical section) it takes around 5 secs. Can somebody explain why is it so and not the other way around.

```
#include "log4cxx/logger.h"
#include "log4cxx/xml/domconfigurator.h"
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>

//#define ENHANCEDLOGGING

using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

#define LOG_TMP_BUF_SIZE        3000
LoggerPtr logger(Logger::getRootLogger());

#ifdef ENHANCEDLOGGING
void LOG_DEBUG(const char *format)
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, format);
}
#else
boost::recursive_mutex m_guard;
#define LOG_COMM 0

void LOG_DEBUG(const char *format)
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(m_guard);
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, format);
}
#endif

const int thread_count = 100;

void printer(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
        LOG_DEBUG("Logging performance check");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    xml::DOMConfigurator::configure("config.xml");

    boost::thread_group threads;
    for (int i = 0; i != thread_count; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(printer);

    threads.join_all();

    std::cout << t.elapsed().user << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.elapsed().wall << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.elapsed().system << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following configuration. Running with/without org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender doesn't make a difference

```
<appender name="appxNormalAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="appxLogFile.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) %t - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="appxNormalAppender"/>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="all" />
        <appender-ref ref="appxNormalAppender"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: My bet is the `std::string` used in your lock-less variant is slowing down the whole process. Besides, I don't see the point in using a mutex. I guess log4cxx functions are thread-safe already, so if I'm not mistaken there is nothing to protect here.

Comment: I tried another variant where I moved the code in log_format to the macro and std::string object was removed but it was still slow. I can't comprehend why it is so.

Comment: I may guess that in 'locked' case you actually output message in the same thread but in 'lockless' case you just pass log message to dedicated log thread via queue so you are measuring not real output

Comment: start by posting the real code that gives you real figures, and then we might start trying to solve your problem.

Comment: This is the actual working code with which I am testing with. I was getting similar results in my production app that's why I created a test app to verify this and saw this. Following is the output with ENHANCEDLOGGING (Locked case)macro commented out
3406250000
5530024898
2359375000
 5.531923s wall, 3.406250s user + 2.359375s system = 5.765625s CPU (104.2%)

Following is the output in Lock less case:
8265625000
4973627016
2468750000
 4.974934s wall, 8.265625s user + 2.468750s system = 10.734375s CPU (215.8%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

OK, I had mistaken the timings by a factor 1000 so I was thinking the logger was not outputting anything.

What you are witnessing is the cost of the condition variable hidden beneath the log dispatcher thread.

You can read [this excellent analysis](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/hpux/MakingConditionVariablesPerform.pdf) if you want to go into more details.

Basically, when you synchronize the printer task before calling the logger, all the printers will queue on your own lock and the logger will be called more efficiently.

If your printers are accessing the logger asynchronously, there will be more occurences of the logger finding there is no work to be done after finishing the last output, so the logger thread will go to sleep on the condition variable, which will consume more CPU when the next printer has to wake the logger.

See this sample program that emulates a barebone waiting queue implemented with condition variables.
Here the logger thread queue has a length of 1, but when you stuff thousands of messages into the system, the queue of the real logger will be filled to the brim in no time, so most of your test program will run with a saturated queue, thus reproducing the conditions in this small example.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define thread_count 100
#define log_count 600000/thread_count

const char * pending;
bool kill = false;
std::mutex              lock;
std::condition_variable work;
int logger_waits;
void logger (void)
{ 
    // process requests
    for (;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> waiter(lock);
        while (pending == nullptr && !kill)
        {
            logger_waits++;
            work.wait(waiter);
        }
        if (kill) break;
        std::cout << pending << std::endl;
        pending = nullptr;       
    }
}

void console_log (const char * format)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> waiter(lock);
    pending = format;
    work.notify_one();
}

void printer1(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < log_count; i++)
    {
        console_log("Logging check");
    }
}

std::mutex m_guard;
void printer2(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < log_count; i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> waiter(m_guard);
        console_log("Logging check");
    }
}

int bench (void (*printer)(void))
{
    std::vector<std::thread> printers;
    printers.resize(thread_count);
    logger_waits = 0;

    clock_t start =clock();

    for (int i = 0; i != thread_count; ++i)
        printers[i] = std::thread(printer);

    for (int i = 0; i != thread_count; ++i)
        printers[i].join();

    return (clock()-start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    std::thread logthread (logger);

    int time2 = bench (printer2);
    int lw2 = logger_waits;
    int time1 = bench (printer1);
    int lw1 = logger_waits;
    fprintf (stderr, "\n   lock : %d ms %d waits\n", time1, lw1);
    fprintf (stderr,   "no lock : %d ms %d waits\n", time2, lw2);

    kill = true;
    work.notify_one();
    logthread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

typical output:

```
   lock : 3940 ms 183 waits
no lock : 4820 ms 16093 waits
```

All this being said, this test case does not reflect the proper use of a log system. It is meant to output a few messages at a time, so that the main application is never slowed down by log outputs.

Comment: I have updated the code again. Now there is no extra std::string object. The logs are getting generated in both cases and the size of logs is exactly same. I am still seeing the same discrepancy. 

Lockless version:
6796875000
4321169446
2453125000
 4.322271s wall, 6.796875s user + 2.453125s system = 9.250000s CPU (214.0%)

Locked version
2921875000
4899806024
2156250000
 4.900910s wall, 2.921875s user + 2.156250s system = 5.078125s CPU (103.6%)

Comment: They are still not the same piece of code. Why don't you write a function that is exactly the same with or without the lock?

Comment: Updated the code based on your suggestions but the result is still the same.

Comment: Okay, now that we are working on a clean slate, I think I've got your answer :)